# Open new tab after submit button and get data of the dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I start learning JavaScript at the moment, I have the following code to generate a dropdown menu in a index.html file

```
<select id="secondbox" name="project">
    <option selected value="">---Generate---</option>
    <script src="myjs.js"> </script>
</select>

<input value="Submit" id="submit" type="submit"> </input>
<script>
// new tab here
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
    window.open('graph.html');
});
</script>
```

My script works well when generates the data within the drop-down menu. Now I am using submit button to open a New Tab with html file called "graph.html". The "graph.html' have the following code

```
    <div id="graph"> </div>
    <script src="getjs.js"> </script>
```

My JavaScript file is 'getjs.js' with a very basic function

```
$(function(){
    // this code works and display TEST NEW PAGE
    //$("#graph").append("<strong>TEST NEW PAGE</strong>");

    // not working
    var searchName=$("select[name='project']").val();
    alert(searchName);
});
```

I want an alert box appears such as "ProjectYZX' corresponding to the drop-down menu selected options in my 'index.html' file on my New Tab Page

Could anyone be able to give me any hints?

Thank you.

Updating part

```
    $.getJSON("mydata.json",function(data){
    var searchName=sessionStorage.getItem("myval");

    $.each(data,function(index,obj){
        for(var i in data.names){
            if(searchName==data.names[i].Name){
                alert(data.names[i].Name);
            }   
        }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to store the value of your drop-down menu in `sessionStorage`, then retrieve it from your new window:

**In your `index.html`:**

```
<select id="secondbox" name="project">
    <option selected value="">---Generate---</option>
    <script src="myjs.js"> </script>
</select>

<input value="Submit" id="submit" type="submit"> </input>

<script>
$(function() {
    // Initialize the drop-down menu's value in sessionStorage
    sessionStorage.setItem("my_select_value", $("#secondbox").val());

    // Storing the drop-down menu's value in sessionStorage on change
    $("#secondbox").change(function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("my_select_value", $(this).val());
    });


    // new tab here
    $("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
        window.open('graph.html');
    });
});
</script>
```

**In your script `getjs.js`:**

```
$(function(){
    // Retriving the drop-down menu's value from the sessionStorage
    var my_select_value = sessionStorage.getItem("my_select_value");
    alert(my_select_value);
});
```

Note: depending on your needs, you could also use `localStorage` instead of `sessionStorage` :)

Comment: @user3063604: Your welcome mate! ;) Don't forget to validate the answer :D

Comment: There is a little bug with the code, if I choose first option at the beginning, it always give me an empty alert box. However, if I choose for example the second option or third option and come back to choose the first option, the code work perfectly. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The given code worked for me :S... Did you check you console for any error?

Comment: I have updated the part I am working on, the code works good without any error on the console. But like I mentioned with you above, if I choose first option of the drop-down box at the very beginning, it will not display the alert box with the corresponding data. I have to select other options to make it works